# What is the purpose of 一切信息 in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning, sentence-structure

#### Example sentence, from 青少年科学百科全书 （第一章：声音）

> 各种各样的声音能够使我们了解来自内部身体和外部世界发生的一切信息。

I've translated this as:

> Various sounds can enable our understanding of events in the human body and the outside world.

However, I think I may have abandoned some meaning.

#### Questions

- what is the purpose of **一切信息**?  I translate this literally as "all information" or "all data".
- does **发生** apply to both 世界 and 身体, or only 世界?

  - i.e. 世界发生 world happenings
  - and 身体发生 bodily happenings

#### a different literal translation attempt:

[image: chunked literal translation attempt]

Comment: 各种各样的声音/能够/使我们了解/【来自内部身体(的)】和【外部世界发生的】一切信息。

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it is not written carefully, 信息 can NOT 发生，the sentese would read better if written as

> 各种各样的声音能够使我们了解来自身体内部和外部世界发生的一切 *or*
>
> 各种各样的声音能够使我们了解来自身体内部和外部世界发生的一切事情 *or*
>
> 各种各样的声音能够使我们了解来自身体内部和外部世界发生的一切事情的相关信息

Answer (score 1):

一切信息 carries the meaning of all the information, in this sentence, which means all the events happening.

发生 in this sentence applied to both 身体 and 外部世界，can be translated to

"Happening to both inside and outside of our bodies" where the 外部世界 meaning the world outside our bodies, you can take it as outside our bodies.